# How to integrate Laravel 5.4 with Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, laravel

I know how to create full **Laravel 5.4** project by its own and also I know how to create SPA using **Angular 4**.

> Problem:

I don't know how to integrate Laravel with Angular.

Also, I want to use Laravel 5.4 as the back-end and Angular 4 as the front-end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create two projects :

- Laravel project which provides some api's endpoint and return some json responses.
- Angular project which calls the Laravel api in ajax and update the DOM in your front SPA with the responses.

Comment: You mean two separated projects and I use JSON as the connection between both? Is that the best solution or both would be better if in the same project?

Comment: Well if you want to do a SPA with the webservices architecture, you can use this solution, with JSON as the connection. You can also use the monolithic architecture and pass data in a javascript object in your front.

Comment: What is the best solution for created a CRM. A system for a company

Comment: Both are great. The monolithic architecture is maybe easier to configure and to deploy.

Comment: can you provide me any video or tutorial for the monolithic architecture?

Comment: In the laravel documentation, you can learn how to integrate a javascript framework in laravel (vue.js in this documentation) in the "frontend" part.

Comment: Here is the Laravel - Angular 4 integration tutorial if anyone is interested https://github.com/toni-rmc/laravel-angular-integration

Answer (score -2):

Other best way to integrate laravel 5.4 with Angular 4 using Angular Cli

[Laravel 5.4 & Angular 4.3.4](https://github.com/ghanshyamtank59/laravel5Angular4)

Answer (score -3):

Best way to integrate Laravel 5.4 with Angular 4

https://laravel-angular.readme.io/docs

---

for existing project update some

https://learninglaravel.net/angular-4-new-features-and-improvements

Comment: laravel-angular project is great but it supports neither laravel 5.4 or Angular above v1

Comment: It doesn't talk about Angular 4, that was asked in the question