# Connect Angular 4 with LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I want to develope an website with Angular 4 and Laravel 5.4. The question is how to connect in a better way this two framework. It`s a good idea to make a subdomain for laravel 5.4 (api.exameple.com) and running angular 4 on main domain (example.com) and connect it to laravel through API or exist another way to integrate laravel with angular?? And in general is a good idea to use laravel 5.4 and angular 4 for a big project?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494925/best-way-to-integrate-laravel-5-4-with-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

You should create a containing folder which you can name anything, probably the project name, like `my-blog` and in that folder (`my-blog`) you should create your laravel and angular projects.

```
ng new frontend(your angular project)
composer create-project laravel/laravel backend
```

These will generate two folders for you in the `my-blog` folder and you can link them by making api calls from the frontend to the backend.